# Django: How to dump the database in 1.8?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I used to use manage.py sqlall app to dump the database to sql statements. While, after upgrading to 1.8, it doesn't work any more.

It says:

> CommandError: App 'app' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and
>   sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations.

It seems there is not a way to solve this.

I need to dump the database to sql file, so I can use it to clone the whole database else where, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: mysqldump > file_name

Comment: They might not be running mysql. A better guess for Django is postgres, or sqlite if just getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dump the db directly with mysqldump as allcaps suggested, or run `manage.py migrate` first and then it should work. It's telling you there are migrations that you have yet to apply to the DB.

Comment: The problem is running manage.py migrate cannot solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
python manage.py dumpdata <app_name> > <outputfile>
```